# struts.xml configuration limit

Tags: struts2

Dose struts.xml has any limit for configuration or dose struts2 has any limit for creating new actions? since I have around 35 actions configured in my struts.xml. when I create new action and used it in my jsp page I evidence that only  is alone executing and it does not gets into my action class (which I noticed while debugging) and returned or redirected to the same page (i.e. the page I gave in ).

Comment: Thats not because of the limit. Some code might help to figure out the problem.

Comment: [I have the full code here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9884067/896718)

Comment: You need to clarify your question--as it stands it's unclear what the issue actually is. You can have far more than 35 actions in a config file.

Comment: @satish as Dave commented twice, your problem is unclear, tons of things can go wrong and we might be looking in the wrong direction the whole time. Please share the exact problem and exception that your are facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You r question is not clear enough especially the part last few lines. regarding other part of the Question you can have as many actions as you want in your configuration but this is never a good idea because

1. Config file will become too large
2. Maintain large XML file is always hard job

My suggestion is break up you main configuration file in to small files like you must have different modules to work on different business requests

- Break you configuration module/package level
- import them in your main struts.xml

its always better to work in modular level rather than using a single file which will keep on hard to maintain and debug with time.

Comment: I got the problem fixed its because of those getters and setters, still I dont know what went wrong. I was in plan to do rework so I start delete and recode; starting from jsp page, while I deleted all getteres and setters and rewrote, it works fine. Also as you said let me organize my struts.xml for clarity.